# Name of dataframe format shown in picture

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am completely new to data wrangling as a whole and I came across this dataframe format (shown in the picture) because of a task where I have to wrangle it to this format from another one. I have no idea what is called or how to go about wrangling it. Earlier I was just familiar with the usual method with rows and columns but not this. It just seems like the headers of various columns have been written in one column. Could someone please tell me what it is called? (Sorry if the question seems vague, I have no other idea how to frame it)[See this image for the dataframe type I am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7homU.jpg)

Comment: Please include screenshot in body of question instead of a link.

Comment: it looks like multindex dataframe which was flattened in a bit strange manner, and most likely with some missing columns...